# C# How do I convert this string[] (from textbox) to a list or an array of IPAddresses

Tags: c#, winforms, list

Ok, I am not sure how to do this as I am trying to teach myself C# and create a program for work at the same time.

I am creating a Windows Form C# project, I have a text with a list of anywhere from 1 IP address to thousands of IP address in it.  When I click the submit button on the form I want it to create a list from the contents of the message box one line at a time.

I also would like to Parse the list to IP address arrays using the System.Net IPAddress Class into an array for each IP address.

I get no errors when I use List list = new List(textBox1.Lines); with the below code:

```
        private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            //Pass Text of TextBox1 to String Array tempStr
            List<string> list = new List<string>(textBox1.Lines);

//           // Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window. 
//           for (int counter=0; counter < list.Count; counter++)
//           {
//               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(list[counter]);
//           }


            this.Hide(); 
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(list);
            f2.Show();


        }
```

However if I try to parse the list here using the IPAddress.Parse it raises a number of errors.
List list = new List(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Lines));

1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments
2. Argument1:cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'
3. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
4. Argument1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.IPAddress' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I was under the impression that the end product of IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Lines) would be a 4 string array of 3 bytes each, so wouldn't a string array work?

```
        private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            //Pass Text of TextBox1 to String Array tempStr
            List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Lines));

//           // Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window. 
//           for (int counter=0; counter < list.Count; counter++)
//           {
//               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(list[counter]);
//           }


            this.Hide(); 
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(list);
            f2.Show();


        }
```

Then I try a different kind of variable for my list and it doesn't work then either.
List list = new List(textBox1.Lines);

get these errors.
1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
2. Argument1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

```
        private void Submit_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            //Pass Text of TextBox1 to String Array tempStr
            List<IPAddress> list = new List<IPAddress>(textBox1.Lines);

//           // Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window. 
//           for (int counter=0; counter < list.Count; counter++)
//           {
//               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(list[counter]);
//           }


            this.Hide(); 
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(list);
            f2.Show();


        }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert this string[] textBox1.Lines to an IPAddress for my purposes.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list, iterate over the array, and parse the IP addresses one by one:

```
List<IPAddress> addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
foreach (string input in this.textBox1.Lines)
{
    IPAddress ip;
    if (IPAddress.TryParse(input, out ip))
    {
        addresses.Add(ip);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input malformed: {0}", input);
    }
}
```